# Autofill formulas with app script in google sheets is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm trying to create an autofill function with app scripts for a spreadsheet. Here is the code, seems like the issue is the formula I'm using but this is the formula I need to be dropped down in the column. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

```
function autofill() {

// get active sheet 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

// get last row of data for later pasting into 
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// create Formula for first row 
var formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2356,'Name of the spreadsheet'!A:A,0)),"Referral program","No referral")";

// get source range - where Formula will be inserted and autofilled from 
var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2, 9);

// paste Formula in to first row (ignoring Header row) aka source range 
sourceRange.setFormula(formula);

// get the rest of the range to fill with the Formula (includes source range). Minus 1 for Header row 
var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(2, 9, (lastRow));

// insert Formula, continuing the pattern 
sourceRange.autoFill(destinationRange, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);

}
```

can someone help to understand what i am doing wrong?

can someone help to understand what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Describe the problem as written in [mcve]

Comment: What's the error you are having?

Comment: The error was in the formula =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2356,'Name of the spreadsheet'!A:A,0)),"Referral program","No referral") and i fixed it by putting \ before the "". =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2356,'Name of the spreadsheet'!A:A,0)),\"Referral program\",\"No referral\")